# ImportError: no module named rest_framework_nested

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I am running through following error when I try running the server:

```
ImportError: no module named rest_framework_nested
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The module name in the error message belongs to the package `drf-nested-routers`. You can install it using:

```
pip install drf-nested-routers
```